# PM2 start script with multiple arguments (serve)

Tags: pm2, serve

I'm trying to run `serve frontend/dist -l 4000` from PM2. This is supposed to serve a Vue app on port 4000.

In my ecosystem.config.js, I have:

```js
    {
      name: 'parker-frontend',
      max_restarts: 5,
      script: 'serve',
      args: 'frontend/dist -l 4000',
      instances: 1,
    },
```

But when I do `pm2 start`, in the logs I have the following message:

`Exposing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/parker/frontend/dist directory on port NaN`

Whereas if I run the same command: `serve frontend/dist -l 4000`, it runs just fine on port 4000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `serve frontend/dist -l 5000` I got an error in the PM2 logs.

In it's call stack I've found:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API/Serve.js:242:4)
```

Notice the path: /usr/lib/node_modules/**pm2**/lib/API/Serve.js

There is *another* command that's called `serve` in pm2 itself that was ran instead of the correct one. This is not the `npm i -g serve` I installed before. This is due to how Node package resolution works - it prioritizes local modules first.

To use the globally installed version (the correct one), you need to specify the exact path to your global `serve`.

To find out the path - on Linux, you can just do:

```sh
$ which serve
/usr/local/bin/serve
```

Then put the path in your ecosystem.config.js `script` property.

Final working ecosystem.config.js:

````
    {
      name: 'parker-frontend',
      script: '/usr/local/bin/serve', //pm2 has it's own 'serve' which doesn't work, make sure to use global
      args: 'frontend/dist -l 5000',
      instances: 1,
    },
    ```
````